# Failed to connect to bus: Connection refused

Tags: linux, nas, systemctl

I am using Nas server, Netgear Readynas.
This is my `uname`

```
root@nas316:~# uname -a
Linux nas316 4.4.190.x86_64.1 #1 SMP Mon Oct 28 01:55:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Somehow can't restart server.

```
root@nas316:~# shutdown -r now
Failed to connect to bus: Connection refused
Failed to open /dev/initctl: No such device or address
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

Also `systemctl` returns same error.

```
root@nas316:~# systemctl status apache
Failed to connect to bus: Connection refused
```

I googled around and try

```
root@nas316:~# dbus-launch
-bash: dbus-launch: command not found

root@nas316:~# echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
(nothing appears)
```

I guess dbus-daemon is working though...

```
root@nas316:~# ps aux | grep dbus-daemon
root      8666  0.0  0.0  17836  1004 pts/0    S+   12:30   0:00 grep dbus-daemon
root     30967  0.0  0.0  40436   404 ?        Ss   Jun13   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=unix:path=/var/netatalk/spotlight.ipc --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

Is there anything I can do ??

---

```
root@nas316:/etc# cat debian_version 
8.11

root@nas316:~#ps 1
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     4:31 /sbin/init

root@nas316:/run/systemd# ls -la /run/systemd/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  380 Jun 19 14:40 .
drwxrwxr-x 25 root admin 840 Aug 17 12:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Feb  3  2021 ask-password
srwx------  1 root root    0 Feb  3  2021 cgroups-agent
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root  400 Jun 19 14:40 generator
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  220 Jun 19 14:40 generator.late
d---------  2 root root   40 Feb  3  2021 inaccessible
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   60 Feb  3  2021 initctl
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  160 Feb  3  2021 journal
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Feb  3  2021 machines
srwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Feb  3  2021 notify
srwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Feb  3  2021 private
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   60 Jun 13 06:11 seats
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Feb  3  2021 sessions
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Feb  3  2021 show-status
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Feb  3  2021 shutdown
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Feb  3  2021 system
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Feb  3  2021 transient
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Feb  3  2021 users
```

Comment: Both the dbus-daemon you were trying to start (a session bus) and the one you see in the process list (a private app-specific bus) are the wrong dbus-daemon. But are you sure the system actually uses 'systemd' in the first place? What's the name of pid 1 in `ps 1`? Does the file `/run/systemd/private` exist?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I updated the article. `ps 1` and `/run/systemd/private` honestly this system is Nas specific linux so there are still unvague points, normally I use Ubuntu though..